# Jodatime time difference between 2 timezones

Tags: java, jodatime

What api do I have to use to get the time difference between 2 timezones without inputing any datetime.

What I am doing right now, is make a temporary date (midnight) from one of the timezone then convert to utz and then convert again to the other timezone and then compute the duration of the two. It is working but is there a simpler api to get the time difference by just giving the name of the zones?

Too long for comment, so I put it here.
server is on diff. timezone, data/informations come from clients from different timezones and save in the db in utc. Problem arise when the client request a transaction history in a certain date. It seems it is not a simple conversion of the requested date (client timezone) to utc, I need to add the time difference of the server timezone and the client timezone to the converted utc time to get the correct date. (so i do it like I said above). Now I found out that the time difference should be added or subtracted, depending on whos timezone is ahead. Well anyway thanks for everybody's inputs. Need the project to run asap so they decided to use just one timezone for the meantime. Implemented or not I will seek a solution to this for future projects. :)

Comment: You could maintain a static map of time(s) in different TZ(s). Calculate the difference on the fly. You won't have to create new dates on runtime.

Comment: @TJ- Please answer with example

Comment: @Nabin I can, but this is not exactly what the OP is looking for. OP wants something from JodaTime. My comment is a suggestion.

Comment: Problem with that is when there is a dst change, need to manually change the map again.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem: what problem are you trying to solve by obtaining this information?  It could well be that Joda can solve your actual issue without requiring you to keep track of this information.

Comment: @jgm too long for comment so I answered above.

Comment: Joda will happy work with different timezones so it sounds like an issue with your code where you are translating from user input to datetime, or when storing/retrieving data in the database.  If you post some code where you carry out the above operations someone should be able to point out where you are going wrong.

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in maintenance-mode. Its creator, [Stephen Colebourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen), went on with lessons learned to lead the [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) project, whose [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes are now built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. Are you trying to get offsets of different timezone without using any additional API?

Below code will do that using plain Java:

```
String[] ids = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (String id : ids) {
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(id);
    map.put(id, tz.getOffset(new Date().getTime()) / 1000 / 60); //in minutes
}
System.out.println(map.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks, what I am trying to do is to get the time difference (in hours) between 2 timezones with UTC as the basis.

Comment: The call to tz.getOffset(..) returns the time difference with respect to UTC. You would have observed the value Etc/UTC=0. You can modify the above code to return hours instead of minutes (Note the int type).

Comment: Please don't use the obsolete `Date` class. Use classes from `java.time`.

Answer (score 0):

```
private final static int tzDiff = TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset() - TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York").getRawOffset();
```

Comment: The `TimeZone` class is part of the legacy date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Specifically, replaced by `ZoneId` & `ZoneOffset`.

Answer (score 0):

## *Joda-Time* in maintenance mode

Since you asked your Question, the creator of *Joda-Time* went on to lead JSR 310 to bring a new set of date-time classes to Java. Those classes arrived in Java 8.

Since then, the *Joda-Time* project was put into maintenance mode, with the project recommending migration to *java.time*.

## Comparing time zones requires a moment

> get the time difference between 2 timezones without inputing any datetime.

That makes no sense. You must specify a moment, a point on the time line, to compare offsets in effect in two different time zones.

Understand that an [offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind the prime meridian of time-keeping, [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

A [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) is much more. A time zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset in use by the people of a particular region as decided by their politicians.

By definition, the offset in use varies over time for any particular time zone. So it makes no sense to attempt a comparison of time zones without a specific point in time.

> What I am doing right now, is make a temporary date (midnight) from one of the timezone then convert to utz and then convert again to the other timezone and then compute the duration of the two.

I am not sure of your goal, but here is code for doing something similar.

Specify your pair of time zones in which you are interested.

```
ZoneId zTokyo = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZoneId zEdmonton = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ;
```

Specify a date.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2022 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
```

Determine when the day of that date begins in Tokyo time zone. Do not assume the day starts at 00:00. Some dates in some zones may start at a different time. Let *java.time* determine the first moment of the day.

```
ZonedDateTime firstMomentOfDayTokyo = ld.atStartOfDay( zTokyo ) ;
```

Adjust to see that some moment as it looks in the wall-clock time of Edmonton Alberta Canada.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtEdmonton = firstMomentOfDayTokyo.atZoneSameInstant( zEdmonton ) ;
```

See that same moment again with an offset of zero by extracting an `Instant` object.

```
Instant instant = firstMomentOfDayTokyo.toInstant() ;
```

Here is the crucial point to understand: `firstMomentOfDayTokyo`, `zdtEdmonton`, and `instant` all represent **the very same moment**, the simultaneous same point on the time line. Imagine three people in a conference call originating from Japan, Canada, and Iceland (where their time zone is always zero offset). If they all simultaneously looked up at the clock hanging on their respective wall, they would all see different local time-of-day yet be experiencing the same simultaneous moment.

Now that we have an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) object in hand, we can proceed to solving your challenge: Getting the offset in use for each of those two time zones.

Fetch the time zone rules for each.

```
ZoneRules rulesTokyo = zTokyo.getRules() ;
ZoneRules rulesEdmonton = zEdmonton.getRules() ;
```

Get the offset in effect in each zone at that moment. Notice the use of [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) class here rather than [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html).

```
ZoneOffset offsetTokyo = rulesTokyo.getOffset( instant ) ;
ZoneOffset offsetEdmonton = rulesEdmonton.getOffset( instant ) ;
```

Calculate the difference between each zone.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofSeconds( offsetTokyo.getTotalSeconds() - offsetEdmonton.getTotalSeconds() ) ;
```

But this offset comparisons between time zones is *not* the best solution to your underlying problem. Read on for a better solution.

## Querying database for a day

You said:

> server is on diff. timezone

You should always do your Java programming is such a way as to not be affected by the current default time zone of your servers. Always specify the otherwise optional time zone (or offset) arguments to the various date-time related Java methods.

> save in the db in utc

Good. It is generally best to store moments after adjusting to UTC. Some relational databases such as Postgres make such an adjustment when receiving inputs to a column of a type akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

Retrieve such a value in JDBC 4.2 and later using *java.time* classes.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

Write such a value to the database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

You said:

> problem arise when the client request a transaction history in a certain date. It seems it is not a simple conversion of the requested date (client timezone) to utc, I need to add the time difference of the server timezone and the client timezone to the converted utc time to get the correct date.

No, not the best approach. You are thinking in terms of local time zones.

When you go to work as a programmer, DBA, or system-admin, you should forget about your local time zone. Learn to think in UTC, with an offset of zero. Logging, data storage, data exchange, and most of your business logic should all be done in UTC. Keep a second clock on your desk set to UTC; I’m serious, your life will be easier.

As an example, let's say your user wants to query for all records with a timestamp the occurred at some point during one full day as seen in Tokyo Japan.

To query for a day's worth of records, do much the same as we saw above. There we got the first moment of the day in Tokyo.

```
ZoneId zTokyo = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2022 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
ZonedDateTime firstMomentOfDayTokyo = ld.atStartOfDay( zTokyo ) ;
```

That is the beginning of the span of time (a day) over which we want to query.

Generally best to define a span of time using Half-Open approach. In this approach the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So a day starts at first moment of a date and runs up to, but does not include, the first moment of the *following* date.

```
ZonedDateTime firstMomentOfFollowingDayTokyo = ld.plusDays( 1 ).atStartOfDay( zTokyo ) ;
```

The [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) is the class that maps to the `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` type defined in standard SQL. So extract a `OffsetDateTime` from each.

```
OffsetDateTime start = firstMomentOfDayTokyo.toOffsetDateTime() ;
OffsetDateTime end = firstMomentOfFollowingDayTokyo.toOffsetDateTime() ;
```

Write your SQL like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM event_
WHERE when_ >= ?
AND when_ < ?
;
```

Do *not* use the SQL command `BETWEEN` for this work. That command is Fully-Closed rather than Half-Open.

In JDBC:

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , start ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 2 , end ) ;
```

Keep in mind that a full day in a particular time zone is *not* necessarily 24-hours long. A day may be 23, 23.5, 25, or some other number of hours long because of anomalies in political time such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).